# Тире не нужно в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

*Россия безгранична.* Нужно ли тире?

Answer (score 3):

А какие здесь есть причины для постановки тире? *Россия - подлежащее*, *безгранична - сказуемое*. Пропущенных членов предложения нет, **тире не нужно**.

Comment: Не нужно, но возможно, если автор хочет расчленить предложение и выделить интонационно сказуемое. Похожий пример: Зрачки -кошачьи, длинные.(Шолохов)